# RecyclerView - Remove Items and Leave Items Out

Tags: android, list, android-recyclerview, cardview

I have a two-part question that I am hoping someone can assist with. 
Essentially I am reading data from an API. One of the results of the API ( in a custom library I made for the app) is whether the result has an image or not.

I am trying to add functionality where the user can remove cards and not show them if they do not have an image. I would like to be able to do this on load (they store the selection) or on the fly.

**Question One**

Is it possible to specifically leave out certain items when populating a recyclerview with cardviews? I can make the image stay out but it doesn't help with the issue of actually leaving the card out.

**Question Two**

Is it possible to remove multiple items from a recyclerview on the fly? What I have tried is a for-loop to cycle through all of the List items and if they do not have an image I remove them. The issue is that this works only half the time and when it does it takes 4 clicks with a checkbox to do so.

Note: The below code is inside of the onCheckedChangedListener

```
if(imageOnly.isChecked()){
    image = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < strains.size(); i++){
        if(strains.get(i) != null) {
            if (strains.get(i).getImage().equalsIgnoreCase(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.no_image))) {
                strains.remove(i);
                adapter.notifyItemRemoved(i);
            }
        }
     }
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}else{
   image = false;
}
```

**Adding Adapter**

```
public class StrainCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private final List<Strain> strains;
    private Context context;
    private boolean imageOnly;

    public StrainCardAdapter(List<Strain> strains, Context context, boolean imageOnly) {
        this.strains = strains;
        this.context = context;
        this.imageOnly = imageOnly;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.strain_card_view, parent, false);
        StrainViewHolder svh = new StrainViewHolder(v);
        return svh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (!strains.get(position).getImage().equals(context.getResources().getString(R.string.no_image))) {
            Picasso.with(context).load(strains.get(position).getImage()).into(((StrainViewHolder) holder).strainImage);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return strains.size();
    }

    public static class StrainViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView strainCard;
        ImageView strainImage;

        public StrainViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            strainCard = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.strain_card);
            strainImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.strain_image);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, as soon as you get the response objects from the API call you've made, you can check if they contain the images or not. I am guessing you have a way to determine it. Assuming you have an imageUrl associated with it; to indicate an empty image may be you are using an empty string or null.

Looping through the objects and choosing the ones which have images should be the way to go.

```
ArrayList<Strain> strainsList = new ArrayList<>();
String noImage = getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.no_image)
for( Strain strain : responseObjects ) {
  if( !strain.getImage().equalsIgnoreCase(noImage) ) {
      strainsList.add(strain);
  }
} 

strains.addAll( strainsList ); //Assuming strains is the arraylist used by your adapter
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Removing items should be straight forward :

You can add an image indicating item can be removed in your adapter's item layout [possibly a red X]; clicking on which you can remove the item clicked.

```
public static class StrainViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        CardView strainCard;
        ImageView strainImage;
        ImageView removeImageView;

        public StrainViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            strainCard = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.strain_card);
            strainImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.strain_image);
            removeImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove_image_view);
            removeImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           if( v.getId() == R.id.remove_image_view ) {
              int position = getAdapterPosition(); 
              if( position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION ) {
                 strains.remove(position);
                 notifyItemRemoved(position);
              }
           }
        }
    }
```

Let me know if more clarification is needed.